# Will the same php and mySQL versions work for both Magento 2.4.2-p1 and Magento 2.4.4?

Tags: php, sql

I have a Cloud VPS account which currently runs Magento 2.4.2-p1.

I would like to install Magento 2.4.4 in a separate account in that Cloud VPS but I'm told we will have to upgrade php and mySQL for the whole server.

I found the following Magento 2.4.4 System Requirements:

```
Composer 2.x
Elasticsearch 7.16
OpenSearch 1.2
MariaDB 10.4
**MySQL 8.0**
**PHP 8.1**
RabbitMQ 3.9
Redis 6.2
Varnish 7.0
Apache 2.4
Nginx 1.8
```

I found this table with requirements for different Magento versions:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

**Will php 8.1 and mySQL 8.0 work with our existing Magento 2.4.2-p1 version?**

The reason I'm asking is my hosting company sent this:

*I can see that those websites are already using PHP 7.4 which is one of the latest PHP versions available. If you confirm we can test them with PHP 8.0.

The MySQL version on your server is 5.7. The latest version is MySQL 8. Please note that we are unable to determine if your websites will be fully compatible with the newer MySQL version since that is fully a development-related matter and something that is out of our scope of expertise as a hosting provider. That is why we advise consulting with a certified website developer in order to review your websites and ensure that they are compatible.

Please note the MySQL upgrade is irreversible, meaning that if we do apply the change we will be unable to revert to MySQL 5.7 and thus, you will have to first verify with your developer that your websites are compatible with the new MySQL 8.0 and that the upgrade will not cause any issues with them.*

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not work. Always follow magento devdoc otherwise you can face issue on some pages or functionalities.
You can check on official document as well.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

[image]

Comment: I have changed the PHP to 8.1 and our Magento 2.4.2-p1 version seems to be working fine. I will now change the mySQL to 8.0. Is there anything specific I should check/be aware of? Is it possible that the values in the table are the MINIMUM PHP/mySQL versions and it's meant that anything of that version or ABOVE will work?

Comment: If your site using deprecated functions then it can throw error. I can't say on exact which page it will not work..but you have to check whole site from your end. If it's working then no issue at all. Also you can run compile command too...Still I will  never suggest to run 2.4.2 p2 with php 8.1